# listのTypeErrorについて

Tags: python, python3

以下のプログラムを実行するとエラーが発生してしまいます。
どのようにすればよいでしょうか？

**プログラム一部抜粋**

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential, load_model
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dropout, Reshape
from keras.utils import np_utils
import numpy as np
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import time

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

w =[0,0]
h=[0,0]
x=[0,0]
y=[0,0]
j=0
# 読み込んだ画像から数字だけをとりリサイズする
z = 0
for i, ctr in enumerate(sorted_ctrs):
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(ctr)
    if x[0] == 0 | x[j] == x:
        w[j] = s(w[j],w)
        h[j] = s(h[j],h)
        x[j] = x
        y[j] = y
    else:
        j = j+1
```

**エラー内容**

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-e011d956ada2> in <module>
     97 for i, ctr in enumerate(sorted_ctrs):
     98     x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(ctr)
---> 99     if x[0] == 0 | x[j] == x:
    100         w[j] = s(w[j],w)
    101         h[j] = s(h[j],h)

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: それから、Pythonの`|`はビット演算子らしいので、論理演算子としては`or`を使った方が良いのでは？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if x[0] == 0 | x[j] == x:`の行がありますがxはリストではありません
リストではないので添字でのアクセスはできません。
そのためにエラーになっているようです。

Comment: ご意見ありがとうございます。
無事実行することができました！